# How to get data from another table matching 2 fields to same 1 field from another table

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-query-builder, codeigniter-form-validation

I have 3 table

**Player** 
Playerid
Player name

**Team**
Team id 
Player1 foreign key playerid from table(player)
Player2 foreiy key playerid

**Match** 
Matchid 
Teamid
Playerid

Now I want a player name from the player table for player1 and player2 in Dropdown box

I am doing it for a college project using **php** **codeigniter** and stuck at this 
 Please help me on this anyone.

Comment: Please define your use case better, do you just need to get all player names to create a team or get both player names in a team or what? Be clear in what you ask!

Comment: I want both player name in drop down which are playing for the team

Comment: That means no connection to the match table, right?

Comment: Yes i want to add team id and player id in match table. So if i select team id 1 i want that two player in Dropdown option which is mentioned in team table. So there is no connection with match id.

Answer (score 0):

Your case looks like a simple `JOIN` query

```
SELECT T.team_id, P1.player_name, P2.player_name from team T JOIN player P1 ON T.player1 = P1.player_id JOIN player P2 ON T.player2 = P2.player_id
```